# Is it possible to set Proxy to GeckoView?

Tags: android, kotlin, geckoview

First time trying out `GeckoView`, I just wonder if is it possible to set an HTTP or SOCKS proxy to GeckoView? if yes can someone point me in the right direction?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun App() {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            GeckoView(context).apply {
                val session = GeckoSession()
                session.settings.allowJavascript = true
                session.settings.useTrackingProtection = true
                val runtime = GeckoRuntime.create(context)
                session.open(runtime)
                setSession(session)

                session.loadUri("about:buildconfig")
            }
        },
        update = {}
    )
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, HTTP/HTTPS proxy configuration is not currently supported in GeckoView1. However, you can set up a SOCKS proxy in your GeckoView by using the following code ,                                       val builder = GeckoRuntimeSettings.Builder()
val args = arrayOf("socks://127.0.0.1:9150")
builder.arguments(args)
val settings = builder.build()
val runtime = GeckoRuntime.create(applicationContext, settings)
geckoSession.open(runtime)

Comment: @Noob_Mern_Dev I tried your way to set a SOCKS5 proxy but it's not working.